# Tkinter : How to access Control variable character per character?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello_, I'm quite new to Python and I'm discovering Tkinter so sorry if my title isn't that clear and thanks in advance.

What I want to do is typing some digits in an Entry widget and have them printed in another Entry widget according to a formula. But i want every digit to be modified, for exemple if the formula is x to x**2 if I type 12 I expect 14  and not 144.

How can I write a callback function to achieve that ?

My code which obviously return number ** 2 and not each digit ** 2 :

```
import tkinter


def CallBack(*args):

    Entry_variable1.set(Entry_variable.get() ** 2)



Appli = tkinter.Tk()
Appli.title("x to x**2")

Entry_variable = tkinter.IntVar()
Entry_variable1 = tkinter.IntVar()
Entry_variable.trace("w", CallBack)

Entry = tkinter.Entry(Appli, textvariable=Entry_variable)
Entry1 = tkinter.Entry(Appli, textvariable=Entry_variable1)




Entry.pack()
Entry1.pack()

Appli.mainloop()
```

Comment: What will happen if the number is `16`?Should it be `136`?

Comment: Yes since 1x1=1 and 6x6 = 36

Comment: You better use `StringVar` instead of `IntVar` and then loop through each character in the first entry to construct the result.

Comment: And you also need to reset the value in the second entry when you input the value,

Comment: I already tried with string var and a for loop but i still don't get it, could you please explain me what do you mean by reset the value of the second entry ?                                  is this what you meant ? : for digits in Entry_variable.get() : Entry_variable.set( int (Entry_variable.get( ) ** 2 ))

Comment: `Entry_variable1.set(''.join(str(int(c)**2) for c in Entry_variable.get().strip()))` and change the `IntVar` to `StringVar` as well.

Comment: thanks for replying i didn't know the strip method but your code seems to return the square of the last digit given in the first entry

Comment: Did you try it? It should include the square of each digit.

Answer (score 0):

Well,if list comprehension is hard to understand for you,you can use an easy for loop to iterate the `stringvar()`.

```
def CallBack(*args):
    Entry_variable1.set("") # reset the second value in the input,And both of variable is Stringvar()
    for i in Entry_variable.get(): # use for loop through it.
        Entry_variable1.set(Entry_variable1.get()+str(int(i)**2)) # each of them **2 and add it to the variable.
```

Comment: Ok thank you sir it's clear now, by list comprehension you mean that right ? [Entry_variable1.set(Entry_variable1.get()+str(int(i)**2)) for i in Entry_variable.get()]

Comment: No,list comprehension is the way **acw1668** gave,which also can solve your problem.